# Would asking users, who ask a bad question, to read some other closed bad questions let them know how bad their question were?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, new-users

It seems that reading other people's bad questions might help new users find out what's wrong with their question.

> Do you find this question confusing, awkward to read, and completely miss the point?
> That's the problem about the question you just asked.

Because a lot of times, even if you say they're doing wrong, they don't know "what they're doing wrong". But if they can "put themselves in the shoes" as an answerer to face bad questions, they may get it.

Comment: They did not read any of the text shown on their screen about how to ask a good question, so why would they read this?

Comment: How does looking at what someone else did wrong help? Generally when you want to teach someone something you show examples of _good_ work and draw connections between where the positive post was successful.

Comment: Even if there were some benefit to showing someone who asked a poor question a _different_ poor question the logistics of picking a similarly bad question seems like a nightmare. How would you find a question that made the same mistakes as the one just posted?

Comment: @JK. I think you may be misunderstanding something on new user.
Many new user who can't ask good questions already think they "have said all they can". Exposing them to bad questions asked by others may allow them to take a closer look at themself question. I think this is much more effective than a broad "your question was not clear enough" description.

Comment: It's far more useful to instead specify *specifically* what they are missing, than to shame someone into figuring out what it is you think you need to solve their problem.

Comment: I don't see any reason why author of the "bad" (from your point of view) question will not consider similarly written question to be excellent and very clear (as they normally see they own question). It may be helpful if author is able to answer that other question... but it sounds like you are talking about users who are not yet have knowledge to answer any questions (and hence don't know what info would be needed)...

Answer (score 11):

I think it will not help them understand *how to fix their bad question*, which I think is the more important goal to think about.

As an analogy, it's like seeing a buggy code, and then showing that code's author a similar code exhibiting the same kind of bug. Seeing the other buggy code won't help that author understand how to fix or how to improve their buggy code. Instead, it's better to show them what a *working* code is supposed to look like, describe how their buggy code differs from the working one, and then how can it get there.

So, [as pointed out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419377/would-asking-users-who-ask-a-bad-question-to-read-some-other-closed-bad-question#comment919472_419377), it would be more helpful to show what a *good* question looks like, describe how their bad question differs from the good ones, and how to make it good.

Fortunately, we already have FAQs and guidelines on how to ask a good question, and there are some efforts like the staging grounds and the First Questions queue to possibly rescue badly-written questions. Unfortunately, those seem to be not enough, but well, that's a different topic.